# Mongoose create object not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I am trying to add a document in collection but it is not adding, I have validated JSON in Robomongo it validates. I have done the same thing with other model it works fine but fore some reason it is not working here can anyone see what is the error.

```
exports.add_ads = function(req, res) {
if (Object.keys(req.body).length == 0 ||
    req.body.user_id == undefined || req.body.user_id == "" ||
    req.body.rate == undefined || req.body.rate == "" ||
    req.body.ads.type == undefined || req.body.ads.type == "") {
    res.status(404).send({ error: "One or more request peremeter is empty" });
}
// console.log(req.body.ads['type']);
new Review({
    user_id: "58492c6f05c095160e37436c",
    ads: {
        type: "view"
    },
    product: {
        product_id: "",
        review: "",
        rating: 0
    },
    rate: 0.07,
    isActive: true
}).save();
res.end();
```

}

if I remove Product and ads, the function works fine.

Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('../models/user.js');
var Product = require('../models/product.js');

// define model =========================================================================
var ReviewSchema = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    ads: {
         type: String
    },
    product: {
        product_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:     'Product'},
        review: String,
         rating: Number
    },
    rate: Number,
    isActive: Boolean,
    dateCreated: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', ReviewSchema);
```

Comment: Can you also show how you defined the schema for the `Review` model?

Comment: @chridam I have updated my post with model

Comment: In your schema definition, change this line `ads: {
         type: String
    },` to `ads: {
         type: { type: String }
    },` as the `ad` has a property called 'type', which is reserved for a mongoose type. Also, the model is expecting a valid `ObjectId` string representation for the `product_id`, and not an empty string.

Comment: @chridam got it thanks. please add it in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your schema definition, change this line

```
ads: { 
    type: String 
},
```

to

```
ads: { 
    type: { type: String } 
},
```

as the `ad` has a property called 'type', which is reserved for a mongoose type.

Also, the model is expecting a valid `ObjectId` string representation for the `product_id`, and not an empty string.